# Sharing Gmail task lists

Tags: google, gmail, google-tasks

How do I share Gmail task lists? Not emailing task lists, but sharing them, like a Google Doc or Google calendar.

Comment: Unfortunately, Google Tasks are very limited in functionality. You're not going to be able to do this without a third-party tool, if at all.

Comment: @Al What third-party tools are out there?

Comment: Couldn't tell you. I don't use GTasks.

Comment: @Al Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could create a google account that you could share and create the Tasks under that?

Answer (score 1):

There is now a great, free, third-party solution for sharing/syncing Google Tasks. It's still in beta and not quite perfect yet, but gets the job done.

http://www.isynctasks.de/

A few notes:

- You can only provide edit permission, not view permission
- You don't have control over how often it syncs, but it's roughly every 15 minutes.
- It only syncs tasks that haven't been cleared (using "clear completed tasks" from the menu).
- If someone else checks off a task, it gets checked off on the other users' lists, but each user has to clear the completed tasks on their own list. This is by design so that each user will know the tasks were finished.

A huge thanks to [herr.kaste](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1526957/herr-kaste) for developing this!

Comment: Please don't copy-paste the same answer to multiple questions. If nothing else, it looks spammy.

Comment: If you are involved in this site, please declare your affiliation.

Comment: @Eddie I debated marking one as a duplicate, but they seemed like validly different questions, though the same answer fit both. I'm definitely not trying to be spammy, just trying to provide an answer to a question I'd had myself for a long time.

Comment: @ChrisF I'm not involved in the site. I did email the developer once to provide feedback since it's in beta, and he kindly emailed back, but that's my only contact with him. I'm just excited that he built the tool I've had in mind to build myself for a long time but hadn't yet gotten around to.

Comment: @kevinmicke - that's fine. It's just that posting the identical answer to two different questions raised some automatic flags.

Answer (score 1):

I have built an app to share Gmail tasks lists: http://gmailsharedtasks.com/how-it-works

Notes:

> 1. With GmailSharedTasks you will be able to sync task lists updates
>      like creation, deletion and updates on due, notes and title.
> 2. GmailSharedTasks syncs task lists in 1 minute.
> 3. You will be able to share hierarchical tasks.
> 4. And last but not the least you will be able to share task lists
>      between more than 2 people, currently users are sharing 1 task list
>      between 10 people also.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own app with Apps Script which will allow you to create shared Google Task List.

- It can be shared with anyone even with anonymous user and they can update your
  task.
- Changes are instantly synced.
- You can share the Task-list with any number people.

Instructions available here: [Shared Google Tasks](http://techawakening.org/how-to-create-shared-google-task-list/2411/)

Comment: To be clear, this doesn't put the task list into another person's Google Tasks - it mirrors the task list on a publicly hosted page so anyone can edit it.